# How to change the color of a ColorCube object in Java3D?

Tags: java, jogl, java-3d

Is there any way through which I can change the color/appearance of the cube. I tried to use the setAppearance() function but it makes no change.

A quick view of what I am doing:

```
Appearance polygon1Appearance = new Appearance();    
Color3f color1 = new Color3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
ColoringAttributes color1ca = new ColoringAttributes (color1, 1);
Color3f color2 = new Color3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
ColoringAttributes color2ca = new ColoringAttributes (color2, 1);
```

Then before adding the cubes to the transform group I use cube.setAppearance(polygon1Appearance);

Later in a mouse event(using pick canvas) cube.setAppearance(polygon1Appearance); does not make any change.

I wanted to ask if is it even possible to change appearance(color in my case) of a ColorCube?
Please let me know if I can provide some other information related to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors are "hardcoded" in this class:
https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/master/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/geometry/ColorCube.java

You can call ColorCube.getGeometry(), cast it as it is a QuadArray and call setColor or setColors().

Comment: I have implemented the suggestion and I can now perform the changes but I have to double click on the cubes to change the color(which is perfectly fine with me). Thanks a lot @gouessej

Comment: @gandalf You're welcome. I initiated the port of Java3D, I'm not a specialist but I spent a lot of time in finding this solution. If there is still a problem, feel free to join the official JogAmp forum: http://forum.jogamp.org